# Вопросы по передаче параметров в Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Пересев с С# узнал, что в Java все параметры передаются по значению.

1) Ссылка ссылается на имеющийся объект, и если до передачи на него ссылалась одна ссылка, то теперь их две?

2) Создаётся новый объект в куче, и в пределах блока кода метода работаешь с новосозданным объектом. При этом после завершения работы метода, изначальный объект остаётся не изменённым? Созданный объект в методе уже стал на учёте у сборщика мусора?

Прочитав пару статей про передачу параметров в Java, решил поэкспериментировать.
Есть свой класс со строковым полем и двумя методами. Первый метод меняет поле объекта, а второй меняет значение скопированной ссылки.

Вот класс:

```
class MyClass {

String s;

public MyClass(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}

public static void changeField(MyClass other) {
    other.s = "**********";
}

public static void changeRef(MyClass other) {
    other = new MyClass("----------");
}
```

Однако почему-то, метод changeField изменяет объект, в то время как changeRef - нет.

```
    MyClass obj1 = new MyClass("1");
    MyClass obj2 = new MyClass("2");

    MyClass.changeField(obj1);
    MyClass.changeRef(obj2);

    System.out.println(obj1.s);
    System.out.println(obj2.s);
```

Вывод исполнения программы:

```
**************
2
```

Comment: А откуда вы такое узнали-то? В Java по значению передаются только примитивы (`int`, `float`, `boolean` и т. д.), все остальные типы передаются исключительно по ссылке (возможны исключения при autoboxing'е - автоматическом преобразовании `int <-> Integer` и других обёрток над примитивами).

Comment: @fori1ton имеется ввиду что сами ССЫЛКИ на объекты передаются как pass-by-value. В java нельзя передать ссылку как pass-by-reference.

Comment: @fori1ton, сто раз разбиралось и даже у нас: в Java все передается по значению: и *примитивы* и *ссылки на объекты*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вы сказали, в Java передаётся ссылка на объект(за исключением примитивных классов типа int, long and etc.) при этом, под эту ссылку выдается своя память.

В методе `changeField` происходит изменение самого объекта. И вы видите эти изменения за пределами функции.

В методе `changeRef` происходит создание нового экземпляра класса и ссылку на него записываете в ту область памяти которая была выделена для копии ссылки передаваемого объекта. Таким образом вы не меняете исходную ссылку и исходный объект.

И да, при передаче объекта в метод, создаётся дополнительная ссылка, т.е. их становится две, как вы написали в вашем вопросе.

Comment: Последнее предложение расставило все точки над i.

Answer (score 4):

В java нет передачи по ссылке в том смысле, что члены ссылочных типов вы менять можете, а вот сами ссылки, указывающие на экземпляры этих типов - нет.

В C# по сути все точно так же: тот же самый код, что вы написали, будет точно так же работать и там. При вызове changeField вы меняете поле экземпляра, но не сам экземпляр. А при вызове changeRef вы пытаетесь изменить саму ссылку, но ссылки остаются неизменными, так как в метод вы передаете только их копии.

Отличие между Java и C#  будет в том, что C# с помощью ключевых слов ref и out позволяет менять и сами ссылки на объекты. В java этого нет

Answer (score -2):

Всетаки букварь по Java прочитать стоит. Все передается по значению. В java нет передачи по ссылке. Вот только `MyClass obj1 = new MaClass("1")` означает что в `obj1` лежит не объект а ссылка на него. В тоже время `long val = 1l` означает что в val храниться 1, но `Long val = new Long(1)` - уже будет означать что val храниться ссылка на объект типа `Long` ( не путать с примитивным типом `long`)

Вот тут подробнее https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html

Т.е. разница между `Reference types` и `Primitive Types`