# Присваивание массива

Tags: java, массивы

```
    private boolean compressRow(int[] row) {
/* некая логика по изменению строки*/
            int[] newRow = new int[row.length];
            for (int i=0;i<row.length;i++){
                if (row[i]!=newRow[i]) res = true;
                //row[i] = newRow[i];
            }
            row = newRow;
            return res;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int row1[] = {0,0,0,2};
            compressRow(row1);
        }
```

Вопрос в следующем: если присваивать в цикле:

```
row[i] = newRow[i];
```

то row1 меняется, если присваивать сразу:

```
row = newRow;
```

то row1 не меняется.
Почему так происходит?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы на этот вопрос

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433241/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-java

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае в метод передается не просто ссылка, а набор ссылок, каждая из которых указывает на примитивы (в данном случае int). Соответственно, если я начинаю присваивать каждому элементу (то есть переходить по ссылке на примитивный тип), то это влияет и на базовый объект. А если присваивать сразу, то создается новый объект внутри метода, внутри него хранятся свои ссылки на примитивы. Верная у меня логика или я где то ошибаюсь?

Comment: Похоже, но не совсем правильно. В массиве у вас значения передаются - примитивы передаются исключительно по значению. У вас проблема в том, что `row1` в `main` и `row` в `compressRow` - это разные ссылки. Да, они указывают на один и тот же массив, но это две разные ссылки, и если вы меняете присваиваете что-то `row`, то это присваивание актуально только внутри метода `compressRow`.

Comment: Почему то не могу найти галку, чтобы пометить вопрос как отвеченный.